# Flink 1.7.2 start-scala-shell.sh cannot find or load main class org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell

Tags: apache-flink

Flink version: Apache Flink 1.7.2 only binary. Scala:2.12

Enviroment:

```
Scala version: 2.12.5   
JDK: 1.8.0_171
```

I simply untar this archive and run

```
bin/start-scala-shell.sh local
```

I got the error :

```
cannot find or load main class org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell.
```

What is missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink built on Scala 2.12 version Doesn't support Flink Scala shell yet. So you should use the Flink binary built based on Scala 2.11 if you want to use Flink Scala shell. A message from *Chesnay Schepler*, Committer of Flink project:

> This is intended. Increasing the Scala version basically broke the
>   scala-shell and we haven't had the time to fix it. It is thus only
>   available with Scala 2.11. I agree that the error message could be
>   better though.

Comment: This is about a year ago and it is still an issue. Will it ever be fixed? Is there any other way to obtain a nice REPL which also can be started on YARN like a spark-shell?

Comment: Know if there is any plan to fix this?