# flink start scala shell - numberformat exepction

Tags: apache-flink

How can I start a flink interactive (scala) shell?
Preferably, using scala 2.12.

However, it looks like only 2.11 is working for now.
Anyways. When using 2.11, i.e.

- downloading https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/flink/flink-1.10.1/flink-1.10.1-bin-scala_2.11.tgz
- unzipping
- executing `./bin/start-scala-shell.sh local`

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x100"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.internal.InfoCmp.parseInfoCmp(InfoCmp.java:59)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.UnixTerminal.parseInfoCmp(UnixTerminal.java:242)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:65)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.java:211)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:102)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:186)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:192)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:243)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:235)
    at scala.tools.jline_embedded.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:223)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.JLineConsoleReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:64)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline_embedded.InteractiveReader.<init>(JLineReader.scala:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiater$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:858)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$instantiater$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:855)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$mkReader$1(ILoop.scala:862)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$22.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$22.apply(ILoop.scala:873)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Stream.scala:418)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1233)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons.tail(Stream.scala:1223)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.collect(Stream.scala:435)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.chooseReader(ILoop.scala:875)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$newReader$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:893)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.newReader$1(ILoop.scala:893)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ILoop$$anonfun$$preLoop$1(ILoop.scala:897)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1$$anonfun$startup$1$1.apply(ILoop.scala:964)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:990)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:891)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:891)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:891)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.startShell(FlinkShell.scala:187)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.main(FlinkShell.scala:131)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell.main(FlinkShell.scala)
```

Note flink is the current 2.10.1 and I try to start it on osx 10.15.5 with a german locale.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317384/sbt-error-failed-to-construct-terminal-falling-back-to-unsupported

Comment: Thanks. Setting `export TERM=xterm-color` is fixing this for 2.11 (still 2.12 is not supported).

Comment: But if I read your link correctly this is caused by an outdated Jline version. Maybe the Flink project could upgrade Jline? Probably I will have to ask on the mailing list.